# Magento: different currency for different store view

Tags: magento, currency

I have several store views (Germany, Ireland, Switzerland...) all which are supposed to have different currencies. 
However, when I set the correct *default currency* on store view level in the configuration - nothing happens.
I hope someone is familiar with this problem. Thanks!

If anyone could tell me where to find the line in the code which prints out the currency symbol in the product page, it would also help me!

*UPDATE
I found list.phtml in /app/design/frontend/default/THEME/template/catalog/product
there the following line can be found:

```
     <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
```

Does anyone know where this function (getPriceHtml) is located?

@ Bixi: yes I did.

@ Piotr: thank you, unfortunatelly the function:

```
public function getPriceHtml($product, $displayMinimalPrice = false, $idSuffix='')
{
    return $this->_getPriceBlock($product->getTypeId())
        ->setTemplate($this->_getPriceBlockTemplate($product->getTypeId()))
        ->setProduct($product)
        ->setDisplayMinimalPrice($displayMinimalPrice)
        ->setIdSuffix($idSuffix)
        ->setUseLinkForAsLowAs($this->_useLinkForAsLowAs)
        ->toHtml();
}
```

is not helping me in finding the bug.  Where is the function which defines which currency is displayed? I am very close to giving up...

Comment: yes, I am struggling with this problem for over 2 weeks now.

Comment: Did you configure currency rates ?

Answer (score 0):

This method is in `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract`

Answer (score 0):

You can also check the method `convertPrice` in `Mage_Core_Model_Store`. Generally price conversion is handled by `Zend_Currency`